# JDK and Maven 3.6.0 installation on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18 64bits

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, sh

I want an `install.sh` script file which can automatically install jdk and maven on aws ec2 ubuntu 18 64bit instance.

I tried installing it, but getting errors and also confused on how to add environment variables after opening the `maven.sh` file with `nano/vim`.

If anyone knows how to get this stuff done, please share the implementation. This help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to work across distributions or is it for a specific distry? For a specific distro, you could use the package manager. If it should work across distributions you could download a compressed archive of a JDK and extract it.

Comment: Hi @dan1st , 
I used, 

`sudo apt update

echo "y" | sudo apt-get install default-jdk 
java -version

echo "y" | sudo apt-get install maven 
mvn -version`

Would it work properly on ec2 ubuntu18 instance? 

My local machine also has ubuntu18 and its working properly though.

Comment: `apt` works on ubuntu by default. However, you can just use `sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk` instead `echo "y"|sudo apt-get install default-jdk`. In one command, you could use `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y default-jdk maven` You can add environment variables from a script by sourcing it.

Comment: Sure @dan1st, will do it accordingly. Thanks a lot for the response. Really appreciated.